# Clonezilla fails to clone to smaller disk

Tags: partition, hard-disk, clonezilla

I am using clonezilla to clone disk from an SDcard (raspberry pi sd card running OMV5 OS) to another SD card.

Now, I have resized via Gparted the SD card from being 32gb to approx 10gb, rebooted RPi with OMV5 and proceeded with Clonezilla. I would like to save this image into another disk that has a size of 16gb.

By running Clonezilla (latest version) I go with expert mode include `-r` and `-icds` and `-k1`.

Result is: partclone fail, please check /var/log/partclone.log
Result from log file is: `target seek ERROR: Invalid argument`

by running `-fsck-y` as a second attempt I still receive the same error.

[Partclone log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnoU4.jpg)

Here below is the description of the source SD Card, so how would you suggest to change the SD card according to the target 16gb SD Card?

[image: Current picture]

Here is the attempted proportionate target SD card[image: Target partition table]

**Answer found:**
Taking off `-k1` will prevent Clonezilla to **proportionately** resize the disk. I suppose that in this way Clonezilla will restore the disk taking all the space necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free space according to the [picture you provide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnoU4.jpg) is only 6.6 GB, so there's not enough space on the destination to write the compressed image. Use another destination disk, or make enough space on it to write the full 10.8 GB of the image.

Comment: Sir, you were right, I took off the `-k1` option and it worked, I supposed it was due to size issues and making the partition table proportionate did not really help.